# PyQT + VTK : QVTKRenderWindowInteractor is invisible

Tags: python, pyqt, vtk, qwidget

I've made a little program to visualize 3D data with **pyqt and VTK**. The `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` is embed in a `QMainWindow` `centralWidget`.

Everything works fine but if I add :

```
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
```

I get a hole (the `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` is 100% transparent). All the other widgets are displayed correctly (menuBar, statusBar, etc..)

I've tried several combinations and it seems like the issue doesn't comes from my stylesheet. I have absolutly no idea about what is going on here.

Any help is welcome :)

EDIT : Here is a sample (python 2.7 and vtk. I'm using python(x,y)) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import vtk
from vtk.qt4.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from PyQt4 import Qt
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class test(Qt.QMainWindow):
    """Test class"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Qt.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("PyQt4 VTK test"))
        self.workspace = Qt.QWorkspace()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.workspace)
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self.workspace)
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        # create the widget
        self.widget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
        self.widget.Initialize()
        self.widget.Start()
        # if you dont want the 'q' key to exit comment this.
        self.widget.AddObserver("ExitEvent", lambda o, e, a=app: a.quit())
        self.cone = vtk.vtkConeSource()
        self.cone.SetResolution(8)
        self.coneMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        self.coneMapper.SetInput(self.cone.GetOutput())
        self.coneActor = vtk.vtkActor()
        self.coneActor.SetMapper(self.coneMapper)
        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.ren.AddActor(self.coneActor)
        self.renWin=self.widget.GetRenderWindow()
        self.renWin.AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.workspace.addWindow(self.frame)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = test()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I guess it is too precise to get an answer. But I believe that it is no so hard to fix. It is possible to notice this bug by adding the two lines (Flags and attribute) to any example for embed vtk in pyqt.

Comment: Hi, by any chance were you able to fix this problem? If you did I'd be grateful if you could share the fix. @OlivierGiniaux